# SQL Injection doesn't seems to work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to learn more about SQL Injection. I create a code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection to see how it works but when I'm trying to input some code, it doesn't seem to work? It only refreshes the page.
Here's the code

```
        $query = "Select * from users where UserName = ''OR DROP table 'users'"/*$name' AND UserPassword = '$pw'""*/;

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row['UserId'];
            $tempName = $row['UserName'];
            $tempPassword = $row['UserPassword'];
        }

        if($name == $tempName && $pw == $tempPassword)
        {

            session_Start();
            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
            header("Location: adminhome.php");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['btnDestroy']))
    {
        session_unset($_SESSION["id"]); 
        session_destroy($_SESSION["id"]); 
    }
?>
```

Here are the list of my SQL Injection Attempts:

`1' OR '1'='1' LIMIT 0,1;#`

`'or drop table 'users`

`Username: '-
Password: '`

`Username: '-0||'
Password: 1`

Comment: Your `1' OR '1'='1' LIMIT 0,1;#` doesn't work? I think the `drop` would be considered a second query, `mysql_query` only executes one query. Use error reporting to see what the result of `mysql_query($query)` does. Also updating your driver will make preventing these issues much easier.

Comment: I tried running them one by one. Also, I'm not trying to prevent it. I normally uses PDO. I just want to try, for once, SQL injection :)

Comment: You can SQL inject PDO... show the `1' OR '1'='1' LIMIT 0,1;#` execution.

Comment: You have to inject code that produces **valid** SQL. Your query is not valid at all: `WHERE ... OR DROP ...`. If it won't run in HeidiSQL, in won't run trough PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is we dont know how are you building your query.

for example if you are using

```
$query = "Select * from users where UserName = '".UserName.
                             "' AND Password = '".Password."'";
```

Then you set your variable UserName to

```
UserName = "' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE table 'users'; //"
           ^^                                 ^^^^   
          close string and create valid OR 
                                             close statement and use // to comment the rest
```

Comment: Don't we have enough problems? Is this something that we need to improve people's ability to break servers? Why not questions on how to defend against SQL injection?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits  OP want to learn. And nothing wrong with that. And if you can break a server with this now days, that server deserve been broken  https://xkcd.com/327/ So dont put the security of your server on the base ppl dont know.

Comment: The vast, vast, majority of the users of SO are builders of great software. That is why I participate in it and that is the kind of activity we should encourage. What learning activity is being gained? Should we teach how to build bombs?

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits You have to know how to build a bomb to understand how to defuse it. You have to understand how SQL injection works to understand how to protect against it.

Comment: You have to shoot someone to learn how to defend against it. This is not how I want to spend my time so I am not replying anymore. This is about to get loopy.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits You dont. But you go to train on the fire range so when someone try break into your house you know how shoot him, This is so basic doesnt do real harm. Is like I stop giving gardening advice because he can make a marihuana farm.

Comment: If someone wanted gardening advice about raising opium (heroin) I would not help them. I would teach people how to secure a house so its very difficult to break into. By the way its spelled marijuana.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Thanks for the correction. Is spelled `marihuana` in spanish :).